# How can I convert this into more (faster!) Pythonic code?

Tags: python, iteration, polygon, contains, geopandas

I have a datablock of roughly 550.000 datapoints, containing, amongst others, Longitude and Latitude.
Now I want to determine in which area block contains the point in the row. There are six area blocks, not overlapping each other, which I have coded into a geopandas 'geometry' as follows:

```
    TMA  ...                                           geometry
0  TMA1  ...  POLYGON ((5.33333 52.80556, 5.60944 52.50750, ...
1  TMA2  ...  POLYGON ((4.11806 52.90028, 4.35000 52.80528, ...
2  TMA3  ...  POLYGON ((5.07333 52.19583, 5.11944 52.20528, ...
3  TMA4  ...  POLYGON ((5.11944 52.20528, 5.41972 52.26556, ...
4  TMA5  ...  POLYGON ((5.41972 52.26556, 5.60944 52.30306, ...
5  TMA6  ...  POLYGON ((4.35000 52.80528, 4.46750 52.75694, ...

[6 rows x 4 columns]
```

To fill my dataframe with the correct area (TMA) value, I came up with the following code:

```
df1['point'] = gp.points_from_xy(df1['LON'],df1['LAT'])
df1['TMA'] = 99
for i in range(0, len(df1)):
    for j in range(0,6):
        if Schiphol_TMA['geometry'][j].contains(df1['point'][i]): 
            df1['TMA'][i] = j+1
```

However, this takes a significant amount of time.
Is there a smarter way of coding to speed this up?
(Yes, I have read the 'never iterate over a dataframe'...etc.). Edit: Perhaps list comprehension can play a role here, however I am too much a beginner to fully grasp what is happening there...

Comment: How is the datablock generated?  At the time that happens do you know what your six areas are?

Comment: I'd start adding a `continue` when the inner loop condition is satisfied, so you skip looping over areas that have already been excluded. That should average you 50% less cases.

Comment: Cool, yes that is an obvious improvement, thanks

Comment: The datablock of 550.000 point is generated from a radartracker per day. There is (currently) no manner that determines the area the points are in. So I have to deduce that afterwards.

Comment: `break`, not `continue`

Comment: You're right. :-)

Comment: Don't iterate over dataframes like this. If you insist, at least use `itertuples`. Note, list comprehensions don't really make your code significantly faster over an equivalent for loop.

Comment: write a Cython script for it

Answer (score 2):

it's me again. I found again an improvement.
Most of the points (330.000) ly outside the 6 areas. So I create a contour of the 6 areas first with:

```
SPL_TMA_Contour = Schiphol_TMA.unary_union
```

And then modify the routine to do the check only if the point falls within the contour:

```
df1['point'] = gp.points_from_xy(df1['LON'],df1['LAT'])
def f(p):
    result = 99
    if SPL_TMA_Contour.contains(p):
        for T in range(0, 6):
            if Schiphol_TMA['geometry'][T].contains(p):
                result = T+1
                break
    return result
df1['TMA'] = [f(pt) for pt in df1['point']]
```

Time used is now down to 15.6 seconds! Proud!

Answer (score 1):

The above routine (incuding the `break` command):

```
df1['TMA'] = 99
for i in range(0, len(df1)):
    for j in range(0,6):
        if Schiphol_TMA['geometry'][j].contains(df1['point'][i]): 
            df1['TMA'][i] = j+1
            break
```

above took 86.8 seconds (on Google Colab)

When I rewrote the code as follows, using list comprehension:

```
df1['point'] = gp.points_from_xy(df1['LON'],df1['LAT'])
def f(p):
    for T in range(0, 6):
        if Schiphol_TMA['geometry'][T].contains(p):
            result = T+1
            break
        else:
            result = 99  # not in any area
    return result
            
df1['TMA'] = [f(pt) for pt in df1['point']]
```

This new routine took 45.9 seconds. About half.
I am beginning to learn...
Perhaps this can be done even faster?

Comment: The key issue isn't the list comprehension, it's that you are iterating directly over `df1['point']` instead of over `range(df)` then indexing into `df1['point'][i]` which is a major anti-pattern

Comment: Similarly, avoid this for `Schiphol_TMA`, probably shouldn't be a df at all

Comment: I am afraid I do not fully understand.  Yes interating over `df1['point']`. What;s the difference with iterating over `range(df)`?

Comment: What would the difference be if `Schiphol_TMA` would not be a dataframe?